# Where is the NilClass in this code? (Project Euler #8)

Tags: ruby, inject

After checking others' solutions, my code here seems very similar to the correct answers. I think the only difference is that the way I define `a` and `b`. For some reason, it says that they are both in the NilClass...?

```
def product(num)
  i = 0
  j = 4
  arr = num.to_s.scan(/d/).map {|e| e.to_i} #can use .split('') vs .scan
  a = (arr[i]..arr[j]).inject(:*) # vs (1) {|product, n| product * n}

  while j <= arr.length
    b = (arr[i+1]..arr[j+1]).inject(:*)

    a = b if b > a 
    i+=1
    j+=1 
  end
  puts a
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression literal `/d/` match `d` litearlly.

If you meant to match digit, you should use `\d` instead.

Otherwise, there's no match; `arr` become an empty array. Indexing empty array always yields `nil`.

```
arr = []
arr[0] # => nil
```

Comment: That works, but now I get a `undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass` at the if statement.

Comment: @KevinC, I don't want to spoil. Hint: `arr[i+1]..arr[j+1]`

Comment: Ah, figured it out. `arr[i+1]..arr[j+1]` takes the value of the index, so it looped through, say, `7..1`. Instead, I needed to `arr[i..j]`. (Also, I had to move the `i+=1` and `j+=1` to the top of the while loop.)

Comment: @KevinC, Yes, it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

You also have a problem with the array indices. The last index of array `arr` is `arr.length - 1`. But your code:

`while j <= arr.length
    b = (arr[i+1]..arr[j+1]).inject(:*)`

is trying to access the array up to index `arr.length + 1`.